# How to build a really cross-platform CLI?

Tags: performance, api, command-line-interface, cross-platform, low-level

I'm trying to find how is the best way to make a cross platform CLI, that's working everywhere: Windows, Mac, iOS, Android and Linux.

I started a thing in C, but building the libraries for each platform is horrible work and very complicated, just tried to build sqlite for windows, I think I'm not going the right way.

So is there a "thing" that can provide fast performance and easy cross-platform building, a thing such as Qt maybe?

Or it is simpler to re code everything for each platform?

I thought it was easier to build cross-platform C code when there's no GUI involved but couldn't find anything.

Tried cmake, but it's very complicated to understand for anyone who always used make and I don't think it's easy to use under iOS or Android.

Maybe there is a Package manager that's working everywhere? were I can install sqlite easily on every platform.

I want to build an API that's working everywhere so a GUI can use it, the GUI that I want to code platform specific.

Answer (score 0):

To build on what @Mathusalem stated, we build out systems on a variety of platforms using Docker and Jenkins.

You could use a setup as follows:

- Jenkins Master (whatever OS you are comfortable on)
- Jenkins Slave 1: Linux
- Jenkins Slave 2: Windows
- Additional Jenkins Slaves as needed based on OS you want to target

You can then have the master create build jobs on commit for both slaves and have them build in parallel. You can also hook in additional steps, including testing and integration, as part of your pipeline.